# Is it correct to use the phrase "With only"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, meaning-in-context

I want to describe an event, which is taking place after a few days, and I believe there is something wrong with the use of the word "With only".

My sentence goes like this:

> With only two days remaining for the tournament.

Comment: Why do you think there is something wrong ?

Comment: I search examples of the sentence beginning with the phrase "With only" and got no result based on my query.

Comment: @RajatAudichya https://ludwig.guru/s/with+only+three+days+to+go     or https://ludwig.guru/s/with+only+two+days+remaining

Comment: And "with just" is often used as well.  "With just two days..."

Comment: I’m sorry you didn’t make use of Nigel’s Comment…

Strictly, your event is not taking place “after…” but rather “in…” a few days… which is prolly why you believe there is something wrong.

”With only…” isn’t a word, and there are not “… days remaining for (anything)…” Days might be remaining “… of or in…” and that\’s not the same.

“With only two days remaining for the tournament” sounds as though it should mean either “…to start…” or “…to finish…” but neither is hinted at in your example.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the use of the phrase, however what you have in your example is a sentence fragment. It's a dependent clause that would normally serve to introduce an independent clause.

Without additional surrounding context that might  explain the unfinished thought, the sentence should conclude in some way:

> With only two days remaining for the tournament, tensions were higher than ever.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I will try to learn more about sentence fragments.

Answer (score 0):

"With only two days remaining" is totally fine. WITH is a preposition and ONLY is an adverb so the combination is perfectly correct here.